# "Incorrect syntax near 'DESCRIBE'. [41,1]" No other context, can't find syntax error

Tags: sql, mariadb

New to SQL, can't figure out what is wrong in my given code. all it says is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'DESCRIBE'. [41,1]

I have tried taking off the semi-colons. I really just don't know what it wants from me.

Here is my code. Anything helps, thank you!

```
-- Write the query to create the 4 tables below.
CREATE TABLE client (
    id          INT                 NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1),
    first_name  VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    dob         DATE                NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT (full_name)  UNIQUE (first_name, last_name)
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
    id          INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1),
    first_name  VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    dob         DATE            NOT NULL,
    date_joined DATE            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT (full_name) UNIQUE (first_name, last_name),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE project (
    id          INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1),
    cid         INT             NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    notes       TEXT,
    UNIQUE (name), 
    FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES client(id)
);

CREATE TABLE works_on (
    eid         INT             NOT NULL,
    pid         INT             NOT NULL,
    start_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eid, pid),
    FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES employee(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES project(id)
);

-- Leave the queries below untouched. These are to test your submission correctly.
-- Test that the tables were created
DESCRIBE client;
DESCRIBE employee;
DESCRIBE project;
DESCRIBE works_on;

-- Test that the correct foreign keys were created 
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'grade';
```

Comment: This isn't MySQL...

Comment: Which of the describes is failing.   I suspect Project is a reserved word.

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...?

Comment: It is the first one for client, but when I take that one out it is the next one for employee, there is something more than meets the eye that is messing things up

Comment: @Nick MariaDB is what im using

Comment: Try replacing the -- comment character with #

Comment: You don't seem to be using a MariaDB system, otherwise it would complain about `IDENTITY (1,1)`, not `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: @Nick yeah you were right, I was not developing on a MariaDB system, I was coding in VS Code then submitting to an online submission thing that used MariaDB

Comment: Do you have some mode turned on to get MariaDB to recognize some alien syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MariaDB (and MySQL) the correct syntax for `IDENTITY(1,1),` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, and `CONSTRAINT` names are not enclosed in `()`. Any column that is defined as `AUTO_INCREMENT` must also be declared as a `PRIMARY KEY` (this is only an issue with the `project` table). So your `CREATE TABLE` commands should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE client (
    id          INT                 NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name  VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    dob         DATE                NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT full_name  UNIQUE (first_name, last_name)
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
    id          INT             NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name  VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    dob         DATE            NOT NULL,
    date_joined DATE            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT full_name UNIQUE (first_name, last_name),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE project (
    id          INT             NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cid         INT             NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    notes       TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (name), 
    FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES client(id)
);

CREATE TABLE works_on (
    eid         INT             NOT NULL,
    pid         INT             NOT NULL,
    start_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eid, pid),
    FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES employee(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES project(id)
);
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=38f8cc17daad0e041126c8f6910af9fd)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know there was different syntax in the different databases, that's how much of a beginner I am. Great response, thank you so much!

Comment: @MatthewJacobsen no worries - we've all been there. It is definitely a pain that not everyone adheres to the standard...